# Any cash machine in central London which can dispense £5?

Tags: uk, money, london, exchange, atms

I'm sure travellers to the United Kingdom carrying an overseas/non-UK debit card can relate to this question.

Most cash machines start dispensing starting from £10 and in multiples of £10. That means if are just about to leave the United Kingdom and you just need £2-3, you will not only have to leave with £7-8 worth of heavy coins, but you also incur the unnecessary non-UK debit card exchange rates and foreign ATM charges for those unwanted £7-8. Are there cash machines in central London / Tube Zone 1 area which can dispense a crisp £5 note?

Comment: Yes! My friend used to hunt them down. I'll chase him down and find out.

Comment: Ones near University buildings tend to be the most likely to, I've found

Comment: Travelling around central London just to get £5 rather than £10 from a cash machine seems like a lot of hassle for very little gain. Just spend the extra £5 at the airport on snacks for the flight.

Comment: If you're about to leave the UK and need only £2-3 are you sure you need cash at all? Perhaps you could make any necessary transactions with the debit card?

Comment: Thanks @DavidRicherby, yes you can always spend the remaining cash in the airport. However, just in case you are about to leave central London and you are walking past a £5 cash machines which you know about beforehand, that would be great!

Comment: Thanks @StephenKennedy, but some London black taxis only take cash. So for a fare like £11.50, you'll get a fair weight of coins back.

Answer (score 14):

Got it.  Yes, there are, and there's even a handy website:

[Link's ATM locator](https://www.link.co.uk/consumers/locator/)

which, when you click one on the map, will tell you if it supports 5 quid notes or not.

Checking the one I remember, it shows that indeed, the BT phone/ATM kiosk opposite Waterloo station entrance (address: Waterloo road, London, SE1 7LY) still dispenses 5 quid notes. :D

I'm sure others will reveal themselves with some searching, as this [several year old article](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-12668840) shows there were still 1400+ ATMs around then that dispensed them.

Comment: has a superb answer. If you are on the go there are three banks who seem to have more ATMs that do £5. HSBC, Royal Bank of Scotland, and Cooperative Bank. Also machines branded Tesco, including inside the supermarket (these are Royal Bank of Scotland but branded)

Comment: Thanks Mark Mayo! If you don't mind, I'll check out one cash machine for real before marking this answer as correct!

Comment: @SumanKrishnaSaha looking forward to it, maybe a photo of the machine too if it has any identifying features :)

Comment: Sure @MarkMayo. I walked past the Nationwide cash machine on Kensington High Street W8 6SH yesterday, but it was out-of-service. However, I have a hunch that the minimum withdrawal amount might still be £10 for these ATMs, and just that they can dispense £5 notes depending on the algorithm. I'll keep a lookout, comment back over here and mark the answer as correct if I find such a machine. Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkMayo, I'm giving up hope for the machine on Kensington High Street - I walk past it every day and it is out of service. On the lookout for another machine and hopefully will comment back soon.

Comment: The URL is now https://www.link.co.uk/consumers/locator/ - you need to look for a '£5' among the icons for wheelchair accessible, mobile top-up etc. at the bottom of the popup. Green machines free to use, purple charge.  What I'd like to know: how do you guarantee you'll get one? Are there any machines these days that'll tell you before what notes it'll dispense before you confirm the withdrawal?